# How to launch activity "ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS" or "ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT" using monkeyrunner (Python script)

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am trying to start activity  `ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS` or `ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT` which are in package [`android.provider.Settings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) but, the problem is these activities do not start.

My code is given below, which works for launching activity "Settings" but when I change activity by `ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS` or  `SYNC_SETTINGS` ; `ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT` or `ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS` then it odes not work...

Although, I tried with package com.android.provider.Settings too, but it did not work.

The only result I get is:

```
Monkey Command: wake.

Monkey Command: wake.

Monkey Command: quit.
```

(I am working at API level 10 and 15)

Please can any one guide me...?

My Code:

```
import os, subprocess

import sys

import time

import random

import string

import re

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(99, "emulator-5554") 

package='com.android.settings'

activity='.Settings'

component_name=package + "/" + activity

device.startActivity(component=component_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
component = 'com.android.settings/.accounts.AddAccountSettings'
```

This will open the "Add an account" window where you can choose from Corporate, Email and Google.

Choosing Google will start a new activity: com.google.android.gsf.login/.AccountIntroUIActivity

To go directly to the sign in screen, use:

```
device.startActivity(component = 'com.google.android.gsf.login/.LoginActivity')
```